# how can i get a list of vector with conditions from dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

i need to create a list of vectors from my dataframe 'patientdata' in the next way:
for the first element of list: a vector of age of patients of Type1,
for the  second element of list: a vector of age of patients of Type2

Note that this is only a part of my big dataframe, in the real dataframe there is much more Type (Type3, Type4, ...). So the list need to be greater than 2 as i asked above, it depends of the number of Type.

here my dataframe:

```
patientID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
age <- c(25, 34, 28, 52)
diabetes <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1")
status <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
patientdata <- data.frame(patientID, age, diabetes, status)
```

can someone help me please ?

Comment: If you are interested only in `age` you can use `split(patientdata$age, patientdata$diabetes)` or `split(patientdata, patientdata$diabetes)` to get complete data? Is this what you want?

Comment: thank you very much,  is that what i wanted